# Why the isometry $h(v)=Av+w$ is a rotation around $P$ when $\det A=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-explanation, isometry

It is well known that  an isometry $h \in \mathrm{Isom}(\Bbb R^2)$ can be written in the form
$$h(v) = Av + w$$
for some orthogonal matrix $A\in \mathrm O_2(\Bbb R)$ and $w\in \Bbb R^2$. We also know that, depending on $\det A \in \{\pm1\}$,  the matrix $A$ is a rotation or reflection around the origin $0\in \Bbb R^2$.

Assume now that $\det A=1$. Then, $A=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\  \sin\theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}$ for some angle $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$. Assume that $\theta\neq 0$.

In order to find the fixed points, we need to solve the equation $h(v)=v$ for $v\in \Bbb R^2$. We have
$$h(v)=v\iff Av+w=v \iff w = (I_2 − A)v \iff v=(I_2-A)^{-1}w,$$
since $\det(I_2-A)=2(1 − \cos θ)\neq 0$. So, the fixed point of $h$ is
$$P:=(I_2-A)w\in \Bbb R^2.$$
So,
\begin{eqnarray} h(v) = Av+(P−AP)=A(v-P)+P \tag{*}
\end{eqnarray}

**Question.** Why $(*)$ is a rotation around the fixed point $P$? How could we explain this geometrically?

*Thanks!*

Comment: The vector $v-P$ is that vector from $P$ to $v$ but shift it to the origin, if acted upon by $A$ then it is rotated about the origin, add to it $P$ again so it is rotation about $P$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v_0$ is a fixed point of $h(v) = Av+w$ then $h(v)$ can be represented as $h(v) = A(v-v_0) + Av_0 + w = A(v-v_0) + v_0$ where $A$ is a rotation matrix. But expression $A(v-v_0)+v_0$ is a rotation by matrix $A$ around $v_0$ because it represents translation of $v_0$ to the origin, rotation of the translated $v$ (which is $v-v_0$) by $A$, then translating it back to $v_0$.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any picture is very welcome.

Comment: Don't you think that it's you who could do the picture ? This picture should represent two parallelograms $OPQR$ and $OPQ'R'$ where $Q'$ is the image of $Q$ in the affine version of the rotation, whereas $R'$ is the image of $R$ in the linear version of the rotation.

Comment: I tried and I think my confusion was on how one should decide to draw the vectors and the points. Shall we consider the vectors as points of $\Bbb R^2$ or as vectors? So an image for someone to whom this is clear will help me to clarify. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks!